WebSocket connection to ... failed in React, but works with Postman WebSocket client
I want to connect a FAST API websocket to a React client. When I try to establish the connection troug Postman it is working, but when I try with react, it shows WebSocket connection to ... failed
My Fast Api is running throgh ngrok tunnel.
This is how the backend function looks:
@app.websocket("/client_messages")
async def client_messages(websocket: WebSocket):
    print("Connected client messages websocket")
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("Client websocket disconnected")

This is the react line that throws the error:
ws = new WebSocket("ws://possum-enough-informally.ngrok-free.app/client_messages");

And this is my ngrok config:
from pyngrok import ngrok
import uvicorn

port = 5000
  
public_url = ngrok.connect(port, bind_tls=False, domain="possum-enough-informally.ngrok-free.app").public_url

I have checked that the url is right and changing bind_tls has no effect.
I expect to establish connection to the websocket and I suspect, it has something to do with the certificate, that is accepted from Postman but not from the browser.
The error seems to be connected to the ngrok tunnel, because when I try to serve the websocket trough localhost it works.

Please have a look at the following answers: this, this, as well as this and this
